# Make width of various widgets correspond with treeview columns

Tags: python, fonts, tkinter, pixel, ttk

As an example, I have an entry, and several optionmenus located below a treeview widget. I am using the grid manager, and the treeview has a columnspan equal to all the widgets along it's lower side.

Since specifying the width of an entry or an optionmenu is in characters (the width in px of those characters is in turn based on the font size/family chosen for the widgets), and specifying the width of a column in a treeview is in pixels, how can I calculate the lengths of both a column and the widget underneath it so that they are visually linked by their positions (the length being the same)?

Answer (score 1):

I found a great example of treeview. It might help to provide some insight. Here is the link

[Create a table using treeview with control of column widths](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/350266/creating-table-in-python#post1487238)